# Photoshop plugin to export visual hints on spacing, margins, width & height

Tags: adobe-photoshop, plugin

Is it possible to produce such design hints (on elements padding, spacing, width, height) automatically in photoshop? Is there any plugin that can potentially do this?

[image]

Comment: I don't think so. I've not seen any dimensioning tools for Photoshop. There are dimensioning tools for Adobe Illustrator (Hot Door CAD Tools).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that in pure Photoshop. But [PNG Express extension](http://www.pngexpress.com/) can help you. PNG Express extension can layout your design specifications onto your design.

Comment: Interesting find :)

Comment: that's very close and a great time saver!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can. I have not tried it yet (but I will) but specKing looks like it might fit the bill.

It can:

- specify sizes and distances
- provide typographic info
- color specs and other info

From their website:

> specKing is a Photoshop plugin that provides tools to generate design
>   specs and annotations

Take a look at: http://wuwacorp.com/specking/

Comment: Found another speccing plugin: http://www.specctr.com

Comment: And another: http://ink.chrometaphore.com (free)

Comment: I am currently using specctr. Its ok I guess. It will save you time on large documents but after looking at specKing I am thinking that looks like a better tool at less than half the price as specctr. I am going to try it